# Replacing line in a txt file with batch

Tags: batch-file, text

I'm trying to modify some `.htm` files, replacing `Name1 Lastname1, Name2 Lastname2` with `Name1 Lastname1`.

I found something [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13219628/batch-replace-a-line-in-a-text-file), and changed the code for my needs:

```
REM @echo off
setlocal disableDelayedExpansion

:Variables
set "_strFind=Titel: Name1 Lastname1, Name2 Lastname2<br>"
set "_strInsert=Titel: Name1 Lastname1<br>"
set /p PC=PC?:
set /p Name=Name?:
set InputFile=\\%PC%\C$\Users\%username%\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Signatures\GR.htm
set OutputFile=\\%PC%\C$\Users\%username%\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Signatures\GR1.htm


:Replace
">"%OutputFile%" (
  for /f "usebackq delims=" %%A in ("%InputFile%") do (
    if "%%A" equ "%_strFind%" (echo %_strInsert%) else (echo %%A)
  )
)"
```

This didn't do anything; what did I do wrong? and how can I find the mistake?

EDIT01:

```
<p class=MsoNormal><span style='font-size:8.0pt;font-family:"Arial",sans-serif'> John Doe GmbH<br> 
Blabla: John Doe, Johnny B.Good<br>
Bla bla bla<br>
Partner:<br>
Bla bla bla bla <o:p></o:p></span></p> 
</td>
```

And I'd like to remove the `, Johnny B.Good` part.

Comment: Where is your source data example and expected results? We cannot tell you what is wrong if we don't have any of this.

Comment: You might want to use `%name%` instead of `%username%`

Comment: What I can tell you is that if your username is part of a longer string, it will never match the word only, the way you run it currently.

Comment: Remove the last character on the last line and the first character on the line four above it, _(hint: they're both doublequotes, **`"`**)_.

Comment: @GerhardBarnard 
The expected result is that the "Name2, Lastname2" is removed in the output.
The " just avoided the html interpreter to read the ">" as a tag they are not part of the code

Comment: yes, but my point is, if you do a stright if comparison and the string does not match completely, it will not work. If I see the input example then I will be able to help.

Comment: Yeah but i think thats a usual proble with string comparison.

<p class=MsoNormal><span style='font-size:8.0pt;font-family:"Arial",sans-serif'>
  John Doe GmbH<br>
  Blabla: John Doe, Johnny B.Good<br>
  Bla bla bla<br>
  Partner:<br>
 Bla bla bla bla <o:p></o:p></span></p>
  </td>

And i'd like to remove the ", Johnny B.Good" part.

Comment: @JonasHuber please paste that into the question and format it correctly. It is impossible to guess, if/where there are line breaks when you do it in comments.

Comment: @Stephan sorry i'm new to stackoverflow i edited the question.

Comment: What you appear to want is to find a line which begins with `Titel:`, is followed by a string ending with a **`,`** and ends with `<br>`, and you want to replace everything from and including **`,`** with `<br>`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As `.htm(l)` files are most likely encoded in UTF8, I wouldn't even try it with (pure) batch.

Check the encoding and try this (untested) batch:

```
@Echo off
set "infile=GR.htm"
set "outfile=GR1.htm"
set "Replace=, Johnny B.Good"
set "Prefix=John Doe"
powershell -NoP -c "(Get-Content '%infile%' -raw -Enc UTF8) -replace '(?<=%Prefix%)%Replace%'|Set-Content '%outfile%' -Enc UTF8"
```

Comment: That works fine so far, but there is something wrong with the encoding.
Letters like ä,ö,ü are displayed with "?"

Comment: That's why I wrote check the encoding, it's important to read *and* write the proper one. You might also try default or OEM.

Comment: I thought with UTF8 its possible to display these letters? But ok i left out the -enc completely and it works now. 
Thank you for your help :)

Comment: Is it possible to make the Replace and the Prefix variables ?

Comment: They already *are* environment variables. It's unclear to me what you are asking for?

Comment: Yes, sorry.
I'd like to fill it in while running the script.
Like this set /p Prefix=Prefix:

Answer (score 0):

This is a [batch-file](/questions/tagged/batch-file) answer which uses [powershell-v2.0](/questions/tagged/powershell-v2.0), *([windows-7](/questions/tagged/windows-7) compatible)*, to perfrom the task.

In this version you do not know in advance any of `Name1`, `Lastname1`, `Name2` or `Lastname2`; only `Titel:`, `,`  and `<br>`.

```bat
@PowerShell -NoP "(GC 'input.htm' -Enc UTF8) -Replace '(Titel:[^,]*).+?(?=<br>)','$1'|SC 'output.htm' -Enc UTF8"
```

You'd simply change the name of the `input` `.htm` file. If you have several `htm` files to modify, you could obviously run the `PowerShell` command in a loop over them, which I will leave to you to code yourself.